# Convert integer to time HH:MM in R (for example: 50-->00:50)

Tags: r

There are a various ways to convert an integer into time, but none of them could change my input into the correct time format.

For example, the integer data with some NA's:

```
data <- c(NA, 50, 1123, 2211, 645)
```

I want to return the following: `NA, 00:50, 11:23, 22:11, 06:45`.

I have tried the following:

```
format(strptime(data, format="%H%M"), format = "%H:%M")
```

which gave me `NA NA 11:23 22:11 NA`

and

```
sub("(\\d+)(\\d{2})", "\\1:\\2", data)
sub("(\\d+)(.{2})", "\\1:\\2", data)
```

which gave me `NA 50 11:23 22:11 6:45`

Is there a way I could convert `50` into `00:50`?

Comment: What do you expect to happen to 20? 20:00? 00:20?

Comment: 20 would be 00:20. The answer below works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work:

```
data <- c(NA, 50, 1123, 2211, 645)

format(strptime(formatC(data, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"), format="%H%M"), format = "%H:%M")
# [1] NA      "00:50" "11:23" "22:11" "06:45"
```

It assume you always want to pad to the left though.